# mysql select query from multiple tables returns duplicate results

Tags: mysql, duplicates

If this question is a little vague just let me know and I will provide more info.

I have written a query that gets data from multiple tables but it isn't working how I expected it too and I am completely stumped.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT students.student_fname, students.student_lname
FROM  students, enrolments
WHERE enrolments.courseID = 'C001';
```

but this just returns all of the students first and last names in the students table and these   names are displayed twice.

Here is the code for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
studentID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
student_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
student_lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
DOB VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY (studentID)
);

CREATE TABLE enrolments
(
enrolmentNo int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
studentID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
courseID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_enrolments PRIMARY KEY (enrolmentno),
FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES students (studentID),
FOREIGN KEY (courseID) REFERENCES courses (courseID)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: It would help to know the table structures between these two tables and how they "Relate" to better support your question.  Think of it this way.  the system has a list off all students and all enrolments it assumes that all enrolements are for each student because you've not told the system how they relate.

Comment: added those into the question

Comment: based on the table design I don't see a unique index on StudentID, enrolmentNo and courseID.  As such a student could enroll for the same course multiple times, thus a distinct/group by would be of use. (or enrollment table needs a year/semester if someone pass/fails and retakes... in a different semester and that information is prudent...

Comment: So how would i go about making a query that would do what i want it to do? I want to return the first and last name of students enrolled in the course with the course id of C001. But when i run the query it just returns all the results. I am completly lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you've not defined how students relate to enrolments.

You either need to use an inner join or add a where clause that show how they relate.

For example:

```
FROM Students
INNER JOIN enrolments on Students.ID = enrolments.studentID
```

Or

```
FROM students, enrolements 
WHERE enrolments.studentID = students.ID
```

The first method is newer and preferred by many; but the legacy method is also supported.

To gain a better understanding of table joins take a look at this most excellent article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Otherwise you get what is called a Cartesian product of the two tables all data relates to all data.

If you do not have a unique index on enrolements (a student can only have 1 class enrolment) then a `select Distinct field names` or `where... group by fields` will also limit your results to close to what you're looking for as well.

============================ in response to follow-up comment===================

```
SELECT S.student_fname, S.student_lname 
FROM students S 
INNER JOIN enrolments  E
  ON S.StudentID = E.StudentID
WHERE e.courseID = 'C001'
GROUP BY S.Student_Fname, S.Student_lname
ORDER BY S.Student_LName, S.Student_FName
```

The group by eliminates duplicates for the same course.
The "ON statement tells the database how students relates to enrolments.
The order by is just to provide a reasonable order to results.

Comment: This could be true if there wasn't a unique index on the student to enrollment table. however if the system limits duplicates in enrollments, this would not be an issue based on the limit for a specific class.

Comment: Thanks very much, seeing how it works helped me to get my head around it. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fetch data from two tables in this way. You have to join tables.